# RecyclerView With Multiple Seekbars

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, seekbar

How to use multiple seekbars on single recyclerview in which each row has different view ?

Comment: question is not clear

Comment: I want to use multiple seekbars in recycler view

Comment: so whats the issue in using that ?

Comment: the position of seekbar is different in every view and i am not able to store its values according to position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the following xml for the background of each seekbar:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/round_bg_progress">
    <!-- or 1dp -->

</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip android:drawable="@drawable/seek1_bg" />
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: You saved me, i was not using <item android:id="@android:id/progress">